# Add vertex locations in Blender 3 Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have 2 mesh objects with the same vertex count. Is it possible to add the location of each vertex of mesh 1 to the location of corresponding vertex of mesh 2.

Example:

Mesh 0 verts:

```
v00 - (2, 3, 4), v01  - (4, 5, 6), v02  - (7, 8, 9)
```

Mesh 1 verts:

```
v10 - (12, 13, 14), v11  - (14, 15, 16), v12  - (17, 18, 19)
```

Expected resultant mesh from geometry nodes:

Resultant Mesh verts:

```
 v0 = (v00 + v10) [i.e. (14, 16, 18)]

 v1 = (v01 + v11) [i.e. (18, 20, 22)]

 v2 = (v02 + v12) [i.e. (24, 26, 28)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with this node setup:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! Is there any way to multiply the two values (or do other math operations) instead of just adding them?

Comment: yeah, should be possible. Check this out: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG42J.png - or course, change the "add" to something you want to have.